# casperjs : Can we organize test suites like phpunit for example "allTests"

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, casperjs

I would like to organize my test suites like phpunit

A script which add all the tests found elsewhere in the same project

Comment: I find my answer [here](http://casperjs.org/testing.html)
Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: thanks, was wondering the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

An example of a small prototype of command-line testing with CasperJS is at https://github.com/mcamiano/friendlyghost .

Basically, it uses shell scripting to wrap CasperJS as a runner, providing test suite organization, test output logs, helpers, fakers, and even fixtures.

Posting it only as an example, not plugging - I actually use Codeception with PhantomJS via Selenium2 as my primary tool. By comparison, FriendlyGhost is not very refined, and certainly not fast for lots of tests, but Casper's CoffeeScript is a cleaner and more extensible language to work in than Codeception's modules and a little shell wrapping can be good enough for diagnostic purposes.